# Unable to upload documents in Chroma DB

Tags: nlp, embedding, chromadb

While uploading document chunks in chroma db using the following code -

```
with tqdm(total = len(dataset["train"])) as pbar:
  for i in dataset["train"]:
    try:
      doc = Document(page_content = i["some_value"], metadata = {"video_id" : i["some_other_value"]})
      doc_chunks = doc_splitter.split_documents([doc])
      vectordb = Chroma.from_documents(
          documents = doc_chunks,
          embedding = embeddings,
          persist_directory = "./database"
      )
      vectordb.persist()
      pbar.update(1)
    except Exception as e:
      print(f"Record Failed: {e}")
```

I'm facing this error. Any help would be appreciated!!

```
0%
27/1238911 [00:23<269:22:52, 1.28it/s]
ERROR:chromadb.db.mixins.embeddings_queue:Exception occurred invoking consumer for subscription 79d77609a7d54a599ae2f631241b5a3eto topic persistent://default/default/f854c239-7829-45ae-bb59-d1a238581e6f [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './database/ba88e3e4-19ab-45c8-8d4e-2323e49fde3f/index_metadata.pickle'
ERROR:chromadb.db.mixins.embeddings_queue:Exception occurred invoking consumer for subscription 79d77609a7d54a599ae2f631241b5a3eto topic persistent://default/default/f854c239-7829-45ae-bb59-d1a238581e6f Index with capacity 100 and 100 current entries cannot add 1 records
ERROR:chromadb.db.mixins.embeddings_queue:Exception occurred invoking consumer for subscription 79d77609a7d54a599ae2f631241b5a3eto topic persistent://default/default/f854c239-7829-45ae-bb59-d1a238581e6f Index with capacity 100 and 100 current entries cannot add 1 records
ERROR:chromadb.db.mixins.embeddings_queue:Exception occurred invoking consumer
```

I have just started using Chroma